# How to change URL but not view Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have a view for which route has been defined. On the view I have a no of images and when I click any of them the Modal Dialog appears with the detail of that image. What I want to do is to change the url only when the modal appears so user can easily share them. And yes, the share url would be another route I will define so when user directly come to that one, the modal pops in. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not change the URL when a modal appears. A modal is an overlay of your page and actually not a new page with a new URL.

Many image hosters, however, show the URL in a read-only field under the picture so that users can copy it. Maybe this is the way you would like to go.

On the page itself I recommend using `$location` to determine if there is an `imageId` in your URL. If so, just invoke the same logic as if a user clicked on that image on the page.

Comment: Totally agreed with you. In fact the currently implementation follow the same. I just wonder if there is a way I can hack this, my client wants to change the location url when modal appears.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to change the url without reloading the page. I mean, you could reload the page every time you click on a picture, with an identifier of the picture added to the url like `pic/123456789` and just do the stuff I said in my answer - Have a logic that checks for that id and opens the according modal directly after page reload. But in my opinion, this is not the way to go here, because that way - all the other stuff has to be reloaded too.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for your opinion and suggestion. I'll keep things the way it is like you suggest above.